# Serializer needs to include more info in a GET while accepting primitives in a POST

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Right now I have the following serializer:

```
class ShiftSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    confirmed_location = LocationSerializer(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Shift
```

When I create a new `Shift` object I can pass along a basic object like this...

```
{date_requested: "2015-06-11", employee: 4, shift_requested: 2}
```

...and the object gets created without issue.

In an effort to make `Shift` objects a bit more verbose about who requested them, I declared a Serializer for the `Employee` field so that my GETs would include information about the employee:

```
class ShiftSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    confirmed_location = LocationSerializer(required=False)
    employee = EmployeeSerializer(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Shift
```

That produced the desired effect: now I can see who requested the shift without making a second query to the server for every single user. Unfortunately, after doing that I started getting HTTP 400 errors whenever I tried to POST that same object to make a new `Shift`:

> Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got int.

I'm positive the `EmployeeSerializer` is freaking out because I'm not passing in an entire `Employee` object, only an `id` pointing to a particular `Employee`. Is it possible to include the entire `Employee` object when `GET`ing `Shift` objects but still accept just a single integer when `POST`ing to create a new `Shift` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a read-only representation of the employee, you can add a [`SerializerMethodField`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield). This will leave your `employee` field intact for `POST` and `PUT` requests and add a serialized representation at `employee_data`.

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee

class ShiftSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    confirmed_location = LocationSerializer(required=False)

    # this will look for a method named get_employee_data
    employee_data = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Shift
        fields = (
            'confirmed_location', 
            'date_requested', 
            'shift_requested',
            'employee',
            'employee_data',
        )

    def get_employee_data(self, obj):
        """ Returns serialized representation of an employee.
        """
        return EmployeeSerializer(obj.employee).data
```

Comment: This seems to work, thank you! @sthzg If I take an object output from this view and resubmit it as in a PATCH/PUT request would I need to strip out any `_data` fields that I've added to the GET output, or will the serializer ignore those fields?

Comment: It will be ignored.You can play with it if you open a detail route in the browsable api and in the bottom switch the form to the `Raw data` tab (or just use curl, postman, ... to issue the request). Modify what's in the read only fields and start a `PUT` or `PATCH` request. To get deeper insights you could also [override the serializer's `update` method](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances) and then inspect the `validated_data` argument. You will see that this dictionary only holds the supported, not-read-only fields.